# Login with iframe popup

Tags: users, sessions

I have popup showing on click on a link on my site which shows a login form in iframe.
i am able to login with popup iframe but when i close that popup, i am not logged in on main site and need to login again.
is there a way so that i only need to login once, either from main site or from iframe?

Comment: very strange. Are you sure that the URL of the iframe is identical with your site url? the protocols (http or https) must also be identical.

Comment: why do you use iframe for loging in to a user. Most browsers dont allow cookies to be stored for iframes. You can use modal forms module for managing login in popups.

Comment: I am showing a page on popup and this page is restricted to anonymous and some other user roles thats why i am using iframe, if a user is not logged in popup shows login form instead of page.

Comment: Ok, it was a protocol issue, i set site to open with www always with htaccess.
Thanks Елин Й.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To maintain the sessions configure htaccess to run site with consistent protocol like www, https, if urls for pages are not with same protocols they login issues comes.